# Parse Server set User ACL and assign Role

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I am converting my code from parse.com to parse-server with little success. The idea of the afterSave function is to assign user only ACL and assign the user to the 'user' role.

The ACL part works fine, however I am unable to assign the user to the role.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(req, res) {

    if (!req.object.existed()) {
        var user = req.object;
        var acl = new Parse.ACL(user);
        acl.setReadAccess(user, true);
        acl.setWriteAccess(user, true);
        user.setACL(acl);
        return user.save({}, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
            var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
            query.equalTo("name", 'user');
            return query.first({useMasterKey: true});
        }).then(function(roles) {
            if (roles.length < 1) return Parse.Promise.error("no such role");
            roles[0].getUsers({useMasterKey: true}).add(user);
            return roles[0].save({}, { useMasterKey: true });
        }).then(function() {
            return user;
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"however I am unable to assign the user to the role". add function(err) to see which step failed, and see error message.

The code you shows is incorrect.

try this one

```
return user.save({}, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    query.equalTo("name", 'user');
    return query.first({useMasterKey: true});
    //first will return one object or null
}).then(function(role) {
    //.getUsers() is equal .relation('users') 
    if(role){
        role.getUsers().add(user);
        return role.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    }else{
        return Parse.Promise.error("no such role");
    }
}, console.error).then(function() {
    return user;
}, console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

query.first() return Object not Array, so you should query, the returned result, without accessing array index. Second last .then block code should be

```
if (!roles) return Parse.Promise.error("no such role");
 roles.getUsers({useMasterKey: true}).add(user);
 return roles.save({}, { useMasterKey: true });
```